# How to add new rows on a Google Docs spreadsheet?

Tags: google-drive, google-sheets

Usually, in desktop version of Google Docs spreadsheet, I will enter a number of new rows if current document has no rows remaining, so I can extend down the document. I installed Google Drive on my Gingerbread and has a spreadsheet file in it. When I open it, I want to do so with my Android app but how can I do it? Which button should I press?

Answer (score 4):

1. Click on the row number in the first column.
2. Click the number again; a menu should pop-up.
3. Click 4th button; a menu should popup with the following options:

   - Insert above
   - Insert below

Comment: This procedure is good to add one line at a time. If you what to add several lines (as the OP asked) without repeating that procedure as many times as the number of lines you want to add, you can follow my procedure (however a keyboard is required)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a **keyboard** (bluetooth, tablet dock...), you can do:

1. Click the row number in the first column
2. Using **shift + up or down arrow on the keyboard**, select as many lines as you want to add at the end of the sheet
3. Click the row number of one of the selected lines, a menu should popup
4. Click 4th button ; a menu should popup with the following options:

   - Insert above
   - Insert below

This will extend the number of lines in the document by the same number of lines that you have selected at step 2.